# Fetching data inside of mapped components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Not sure how best to phrase this question, other than asking for a clean way to do it.

I have an array of objects each containing a name and a URL, i'm mapping over each item so i can fetch data from the URL and display it, however there are hundreds of items, meaning hundreds of fetch requests.

This is what i have:

Index.js:

```
const fruits = [
  { name: "apple", url: "http://foo" },
  { name: "banana", url: "http://bar" },
];

const App = () => {
  return fruits.map((fruit) => {
    <FruitContainer fruit={fruit} />;
  });
};
```

FruitContainer.js

```
const FruitContainer = (fruit) => {
  const [fruitData, setFruitData] = useState({});

  const getFruitData = async () => {
    const data = await fetch(fruit.url);
    let json = await data.json();
    setFruitData(json);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getFruitData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Text>{fruitData.name}</Text>
      <Text>{fruitData.color}</Text>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: You might try making your requests outside of the FruitContainer by mapping over the list of fruits to create an array of promises, awaiting Promise.all, and then mapping over the results. Not sure if this would be the best way, though.

Answer (score 0):

instead of mapping in parent container send a array to child component and then create a use effect and inside useeffect pass a if condition pass a condition and then do rest of your requests otherwise it will make it slow use dynamic import